# ASP.NET C# AJAX Autocomplete does not work on TabContainer

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I'm using an ajax autocomplete for my textbox for intellisense, works fine on my main page without any update panels whatsoever, but once placed inside a **Tab Container** (ASP.NET control) My intellisense (textbox autcomplete) does not work anymore. Any help would be very much apprciated, shown below is the jquery I used to bind my textbox and the properties to my textbox. Thanks!

Jquery ---
`j(document).ready(function () { j('#TextBox1').autocomplete({ source: 'ItemNewNameHandler.ashx' });`

Textbox properties

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
                                                                         <ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender ID="TextBox1_AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server" BehaviorID="TextBox1_AutoCompleteExtender" MinimumPrefixLength="-1" ServiceMethod="spGetNewItemNames" DelimiterCharacters="" ServicePath="" TargetControlID="TextBox1">
                                                                         </ajaxToolkit:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

Comment: could you create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, simply saying it doesn't work doesn't give people much to go off

Comment: can you assign css class for Textbox1 as txtBox1 and change your selector in jquery using .txtBox1?

Comment: @PatrickHume I indicated the problem on my question if you'd just read it carefully. Main problem is, my textbox with autocomplete extender works fine on main page without update panel whatsoever, but when placed INSIDE a TABCONTAINER which is another asp.net control, it suddenly does not work anymore. I have no errors it's just the autocomplete dies once placed inside a TABCONTAINER.

Comment: I only mean its hard to help without an example to work off, are you using the asp:ScriptManager  ? <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" EnablePartialRendering="true" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>